# RTL: name option in getByRole

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I have been practicing RTL in testing-playground.com and saw this behavior. below is the markup I'm playing with

```
<div role="option">
  <div role="item">
    Apple
  </div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
<div role="option">
  ...
</div>
```

In the above markup `screen.getByRole('option', {name: /apple/i})` return the outer div element wrapping the option Apple with attribute `role='option'` . However, `screen.getByRole('item', {name: /apple/i})` doesn't return anything. I expected the inner div element with attribute `role="item"`. Can anyone explain this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no `item` role in the [ARIA role list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques#roles). You can't create a "custom role". Instead, you can query it by its text content:

```
<div role="option">
  <div>
    Apple
  </div>
</div>

// find by element's text content, not its accessible name.
screen.getByText(/apple/i);
```

The possible accessible names of an HTML `div` element are:

```
aria-labelledby
aria-label
title
```

`div`'s accessible name is **not** its text content. So if you want to find element by its role and accessible name, you can add `title` attribute to `div` element.

```
<div
  role="item"
  title="apple"
>
  Apple
</div>

// it works 
screen.getByRole('item', { name: /apple/i })
```

You can use the `Chrome DevTools` => inspect element => accessibility pane to check the accessible names of an HTML element.

[image]

See more [Full accessibility tree in Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/full-accessibility-tree/)

Comment: I got your point and it is working with a valid role in the ARIA role list. But I can access the element with `screen.getByRole('item')`  why is that ?

Comment: @AravindEmmadishetty Updated answer, please check.

Comment: Does custom roles work? If it works what is difference in behavior for custom role and other existing ARIA roles ?